# Indexing a list with an empty index

Tags: r, list, indexing

The technique of indexing a data frame with an empty index features several times in Hadley Wickam's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/), but is only explained there in passing. I'm trying to figure out the rules governing indexing a list with an empty index. Consider the following four statements.

```
> (l <- list(a = 1, b = 2))
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

> (l[] <- list(c = 3))
$c
[1] 3

> l
$a
[1] 3

$b
[1] 3

> l[]
$a
[1] 3

$b
[1] 3
```

Questions:

1. Why is the output from second statement different from the output from the third statement? Isn't assignment supposed to return the object being assigned to, in which case the second statement should yield the same output as the third one?
2. How come did the assignment in the second statement result in the output shown after the third statement? What are the rules governing assignment to an emptily indexed list?
3. How come did the fourth statement yield the output shown? What are the rules governing indexing a list with an empty index when it is not on the left hand side of an assignment?

Comment: You need a data frame here to illustrate the reason I use this technique in the book (to preserve the attributes of the object being assigned to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short  `l[]` will return the whole list.

```
(l <- list(a = 1, b = 2))
l[]
```

`l[] <- list(c=3)` is essentially reassigning what was assigned to each index to now be the result of `list(c=3)`.  For this example, it is the same as saying `l[[1]] <- 3` and `l[[2]] <- 3`.  From the `?'['` page, which mentions empty indexing a few times:

> When an index expression appears on the left side of an assignment (known as subassignment) then that part of x is set to the value of the right hand side of the assignment.

and also

> An empty index selects all values: this is most often used to replace all the entries but keep the attributes.

So, I roughly take this to mean each index of `l` should evaluate to `list(c=3)`.

When you enter `(l[] <- list(c = 3))` what is being returned is the replacement value.  When you then enter `l` or `l[]` you will see that the values at each index have been replaced by `list(c=3)`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer, check this out. Note that the behaviour is totally the same with ordinary vectors and lists, so it cannot be labeled as "list-specific".

```
v <- 1:3
names(v) <- c("one", "two", "three")
r <- 4:5
names(r) <- c("four", "five")
(v[] <- r)

  four  five 
     4     5 
Warning message:
In v[] <- r :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

v

  one   two three 
    4     5     4
```

Assignment via subsetting keeps initial attributes (here, names). So names from the right side of the assigment are lost. What is also important, assigning via subsetting follows recycling rules. In your example, all values are reassigned to 3, in my example there is a partial recycling with a warning due to length incompatibility.

To sum up,

1. Assignment with `<-` returns evaluated right hand side **before** applying recycling rules.
2. This happens because of **recycling**, since lengths of two objects differ.
3. Without assignment operator, `l` or `v` is essentially the same as `l[]` or `v[]`.